# What temperature are faucet feed lines rated for? (don't want them to leach into potable fluid)

Tags: plumbing

I am planning on using the flexible faucet feed lines for a project I am working on.  (they have a metallic outside and I suspect vinyl or plastic interior)

The temperature of the fluid that I will be running though it (maple sap) will be around 100F to 180F - but I don't know yet.  I am building a preheater out of copper tube and need a way to connect two parts that are fixed but must be able to disconnect

I don't want the part to fail or break down and I do not want the material to leach into the fluid.

Are these feed lines acceptable for temps to 180F?

Is there another alternative that allows flexibility and easy connect/disconnect on one side of the part?

Comment: I think you are reaching an upper limit with 180F. I think those pipes are rated to 215F. but to be honest i am not sure if its a good idea to use those for food stuffs.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I made a preheater for maple sap (for making maple syrup)  Copper pipe sits in a hood over a pan of boiling sap.  Steam rises, condenses on the copper and transfers heat.  The sap runs through the pipe and I need flexible connections on two parts - also ones that would be able to be taken off and on with ease.  Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

The tubing should have a stamp on the side that says what temperature range it can handle.