# What options do I have for quick disconnects for copper/plumbing?

Tags: plumbing

[(Related to this question)](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8295/what-temperature-are-faucet-feed-lines-rated-for-dont-want-them-to-leach-into) but I think that may be too specific in that I already had an idea of how to solve the problem - perhaps the better way is to pose the problem and ask for the best solutions:

PROBLEM:
I have a tank of fluid that has to get connected to a movable set of copper pipes/tubes.  I will be connecting and disconnecting a few times per year to clean, etc.

The fluid going through the system will be for food use (maple sap turned into maple syrup)

What is the best way to allow connections to be taken on and off and keep food quality integrity and connect copper pipes together?

The temperature of the fluid will reach (potentially) 180F and I want no leaching of plastic or vinyl, etc.

Answer (score 8):

You might want to take a look at what micro-breweries use.  The connections between the various tanks are fairly modular, allowing the wort to be pumped out of the mash tun, through a heat exchanger, and into the holding vessels.  From what I've seen, the pipes have flanges that are held together by a circular clamp.

Answer (score 2):

For a really quick disconnects, use all-brass garden hose quick couplers.
For occasional disconnects, use  brass/copper unions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can look at Compression fittings for copper pipes (see [here](http://itap.it/fittings/20/compression-fittings-for-copper-pipes.asp) for instance).

Comment: These might be OK, but they're not particularly easy to remove.